# Return Array to Parent Subroutine From Called Function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, subroutine

All,

I am running into a problem passing a 2-D array from a called function back to the subroutine that called it.

EX:

```
Sub Rotate_Stiffness_3D()
'Setting Things Up
Dim Theta_p As Double
Dim Theta_q As Double
Dim Theta_r As Double
Dim Tep(6, 6) As Double
Dim Teq(6, 6) As Double
Dim Ter(6, 6) As Double

Theta_p = Sheets("Transformations").Cells(2, 3)
Theta_q = Sheets("Transformations").Cells(3, 3)
Theta_r = Sheets("Transformations").Cells(4, 3)
Tep = Get_Tep (Theta_p)
End Sub


Function Get_Tep(Theta_p As Double) As Variant
'Setting things Up
Dim cp As Double
Dim sp As Double
Dim t(6, 6) As Double

cp = Cos(Theta_p)
sp = Sin(Theta_p)

t(1, 1) = 1
t(1, 2) = 0  'This continues for a while
t(6, 5) = sp
t(6, 6) = cp
Return t
End Function
```

However, I continually get compiler errors on the `Return t` and `Tep = Get_Tep (Theta_p)` lines of code.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Use `Get_Tep = t` instead of `Return t`

Comment: Return in not a VBA command. Vlado is correct.

Comment: @Vlado That resolved the error on the `Return t` line.  Thank You!

Comment: I am still getting a "Compile Error: Can't assign to array" on the `Tep = Get_Tep(Theta_p)` line of code

Comment: You could do this `Dim Ter() As Double` or `Dim Ter As Variant`.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You can only assign to dynamic arrays (arrays defined as variant or name()).  You can't assign to fixed arrays e.g. tep(6,6).